# How to initialize stanfordNLP pipeline once and use many times without initializing again?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I want to initialize stanfordNLP pipelince once and use it many times without initializing it again, to improve the execution time.

Is it possible?

I have code:

```
    public static boolean isHeaderMatched(String string) {

    // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object.
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner");

    RedwoodConfiguration.current().clear().apply();
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    Env env = TokenSequencePattern.getNewEnv();
    env.setDefaultStringMatchFlags(NodePattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    env.setDefaultStringPatternFlags(Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Annotation document = new Annotation(string);

    // use the pipeline to annotate the document we created
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

    CoreMapExpressionExtractor extractor = CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(env, "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/career_objective.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/personal_info.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/education.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/work_experience.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/certification.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/publication.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/award_achievement.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/hobbies_interest.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/lang_known.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/project_details.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/skill-set.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/misc_header.rule");

    boolean flag = false;
    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
        List<MatchedExpression> matched = extractor.extractExpressions(sentence);
        //System.out.println("Probable Header is : " + matched);
        Set<String> uniqueMatchedKeyWordSet = DocumentParserUtil.removeDuplicate(matched);
        System.out.println("Matched: " + uniqueMatchedKeyWordSet + " and Size of MatchedSet: " + uniqueMatchedKeyWordSet.size());

        //checked if the more than half the no. of word in header(string) is matched
        if ((matched.size() >= uniqueMatchedKeyWordSet.size()) && !matched.isEmpty() && matched.size() >= Math.floorDiv(string.split("\\s").length, 2)) {
                //System.out.println("This is sure a header!");
            flag = true;
        } else {
            flag = false;
        }
  /*for(MatchedExpression phrase: matched){
    System.out.println("matched header type: " + phrase.getValue().get());
  }*/
    }
    return flag;
}
```

I want to execute this part of code to be executed only at first call of above method to load the model.

```
    // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object.
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner");

    RedwoodConfiguration.current().clear().apply();
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    Env env = TokenSequencePattern.getNewEnv();
    env.setDefaultStringMatchFlags(NodePattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    env.setDefaultStringPatternFlags(Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could move the `StanfordCoreNLP` variable from the function's scope to the class' scope and put the code you want executed into a `static { }` block.

Comment: If I put last mentioned code block inside `static { }` block then, two variable `pipeline` and `env` is not being detected inside a static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an example of what you can do:

```
public class Example {
    private static StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;
    private static Env env;

    static {
        // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object.
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner");

        RedwoodConfiguration.current().clear().apply();
        pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

        env = TokenSequencePattern.getNewEnv();
        env.setDefaultStringMatchFlags(NodePattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        env.setDefaultStringPatternFlags(Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    }

    public static boolean isHeaderMatched(String string) {
        Annotation document = new Annotation(string);

        // use the pipeline to annotate the document we created
        pipeline.annotate(document);
        List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

        CoreMapExpressionExtractor extractor = CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(env, "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/career_objective.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/personal_info.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/education.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/work_experience.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/certification.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/publication.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/award_achievement.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/hobbies_interest.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/lang_known.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/project_details.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/skill-set.rule", "./app/utils/Summarizer/mapping/misc_header.rule");

        boolean flag = false;
        for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
            List<MatchedExpression> matched = extractor.extractExpressions(sentence);
            //System.out.println("Probable Header is : " + matched);
            Set<String> uniqueMatchedKeyWordSet = DocumentParserUtil.removeDuplicate(matched);
            System.out.println("Matched: " + uniqueMatchedKeyWordSet + " and Size of MatchedSet: " + uniqueMatchedKeyWordSet.size());

            // checked if the more than half the no. of word in header(string) is matched
            if ((matched.size() >= uniqueMatchedKeyWordSet.size()) && !matched.isEmpty() && matched.size() >= Math.floorDiv(string.split("\\s").length, 2)) {
                flag = true;
            } else {
                flag = false;
            }

        }

        return flag;
    }

}
```

In the above code the `static` block will be executed when the class is loaded. If you do not wish for this behavior then allow access to an `init` method, like the following:

```
public class Example {
    private static StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;
    private static Env env;

    public static init() {
        // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object.
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner");

        RedwoodConfiguration.current().clear().apply();
        pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

        env = TokenSequencePattern.getNewEnv();
        env.setDefaultStringMatchFlags(NodePattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        env.setDefaultStringPatternFlags(Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    }

    public static boolean isHeaderMatched(String string) {
        // code left out for brevity
    }

}
```

Which can be called from another class using:

```
Example.init();
Example.isHeaderMatched("foobar");
```

---

While writing this answer I noticed a possible flaw in your logic. The following code may not produce the behavior you desire.

```
boolean flag = false;
for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
    List<MatchedExpression> matched = extractor.extractExpressions(sentence);
    //System.out.println("Probable Header is : " + matched);
    Set<String> uniqueMatchedKeyWordSet = DocumentParserUtil.removeDuplicate(matched);
    System.out.println("Matched: " + uniqueMatchedKeyWordSet + " and Size of MatchedSet: " + uniqueMatchedKeyWordSet.size());

    // checked if the more than half the no. of word in header(string) is matched
    if ((matched.size() >= uniqueMatchedKeyWordSet.size()) && !matched.isEmpty() && matched.size() >= Math.floorDiv(string.split("\\s").length, 2)) {
        flag = true;
    } else {
        flag = false;
    }

}
```

You're iterating over every `CoreMap` in the `List<CoreMap>` collection `sentences`. Every iteration you set `flag` to the result of the conditional, this is where the problem lies. The boolean `flag` will only reflect the result of the last `sentence` run through the conditional. If you need to know the result for each `sentence` then you should have a list of booleans to keep track of the results, otherwise remove the loop and just check the last sentence (because that's what your loop is doing anyways).